# Google reCaptcha IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, captcha, recaptcha

Is Google reCaptcha v2 supported in Internet Explorer 8?

If not is there any suitable Internet Explorer 8 compatible captchas?

I am seeing a issue where the reCaptcha code is trying to use the method getContext.

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'
```

Comment: Did your issue got resolved? I have recently implemented recaptcha and it worked on IE8, however past couple of days back an error occurring on IE8 Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf', i did a search on google forum and it looks like it's happening recently as they updated the code.

Comment: There is a parameter to the widget which is something like "fallback" which reverts back to V1 I believe which works. I shall confirm tomorrow.

Comment: I have not noticed this fallback option in the reCaptcha V2 documentation. Would be great if you can point out to the page? Thanks

Comment: I'll add it as a answer to format the code properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code I ended up using to support IE8 was the following.

```
<!--[if !IE 8]><!--><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?fallback=true"></script><![endif]-->
```

The difference being fallback=true is set which reverts back to V1 of recaptcha.