# reCAPTCHA triggering Java warning in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, captcha, recaptcha

We recently added reCAPTCHA 2.0 to our site and now we're occasionally getting a message from IE about Java. Here is the message:

> The page you are viewing uses Java. More information on Java support
>   is available from the Microsoft website.

[image: IE Warning message]

Our site does not make use of Java on the client (no applets, etc.) so this is unexpected. This appears to happen when the user clicks "I am not a robot" and before the user is verified. It happens only on machines without Java installed, and seems to happen only once and then a reboot is required to get it to appear again.

Any else experiencing this?

Comment: We are seeing this to with some modern.ie VM in IE10.

Comment: I've just had this reported too and confirm it happening in a modern.ie VM

Comment: Seeing this too in testing a new site with IE10 (IE10 w/ automatic updates). May have to use a different captcha.

Comment: We have had users start to see this as well. No idea why this is happening, looking at the network I can't see recaptcha loading any java either, just javascript.

Comment: Issue is still there. Google doesn't test in IE? I guess I don't either.

Comment: Seeing the same on IE 11.0.9600.18015 as of October 16 2015.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google reCaptcha IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808572/google-recaptcha-ie8)

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning, there were many implementations of reCAPTCHA, and you could choose the one that best suits your application. Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param) suggests to me that the reCAPTCHA widget may, indeed, be a Java control, or that the control that loads into a page that runs in Internet Explorer is a Java applet. Since Internet Explorer is deprecated, I suspect that Google hasn't bothered to update it, and probably won't.