# Google recaptcha not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I go through many sites for its solution and change in my IE8 settings as per guideline from some links.
I just want to solve this problem using JS, Is there any way to solve or any hack for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google reCaptcha IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808572/google-recaptcha-ie8) Have you tried this?

Comment: You need an fallback to google's re-Captcha v1 for older browsers.

Comment: This question is still in need of a [mcve].